# How should I update user.profile on subsequent login (something similar to Accounts.onCreateUser)?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been poking around in the Accounts packages, using a modified version of the ever-fabulous EventedMind [Customizing Login](https://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-customizing-login) screencast.

I modified it to use facebook instead of github, and I noticed something when trying to update `user.profile` information. Specifically, I'm looking for the right way/place to handle changes to `user.profile`.

Let's say, for example, that I authenticate as a FB user for the first time. When I do this, the `CreateUser` event will fire.
Using `Accounts.onCreateUser(...)`, I can populate additional information from the FB graph into the profile, like so:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user){

var accessToken = user.services.facebook.accessToken,
    result;

result = Meteor.http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.services.facebook.username, {
    params: {
        access_token:accessToken,
        fields: ['picture', 'name','first_name','last_name','username','link','location','bio','relationship_status','email','timezone','locale']
    }
});

if (result.error){
    throw result.error;
}

user.profile = result.data; //lazily adding everything
return user;

});
```

This works just fine when the user is created. It's nice and clean.

But now let's say that some of the information changes. For example, let's say that the profile picture changes. If I log out and then back in to the meteor application, `Accounts.onCreateUser(...)` doesn't fire, because the user already exists. It's not being created again, it's being modified.

I need to update the `user.profile` on subsequent logins, or at least check for changes and then modify as needed. I'd ideally like to do this in similar fashion to `.onCreateUser`. Maybe with a `.onModifyUser` or something...

I can figure a couple of ways to do this using some checking and/or client-side code, but I'm wondering if there is an already-existing server hook that would be cleaner.

Any recommendations on the cleanest way to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're manually calling the login functions you can pass a callback as the last parameter which will get called on the client after the login completes. See: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_loginwithpassword.

```
Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function (err) { /* make a Meteor method call here */ });
```

There are no documented server side callbacks at the moment.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but wanted to make sure.  I'm thinking I may bake it in on the server side using an observer... Thanks Chris!